# image classificaiton : TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, keras, multiclass-classification

i am running image classificaiton for stl10, where i want to find the accuracy for model

```
 # Data Feed
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)
train_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR, 
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
val_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VAL_DIR, 
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
test_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=TEST_DIR, 
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
    batch_size=TEST_BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="input",
    shuffle=False
)

# Class Names
class_names = dict()
with open(CLASS_NAMES_LOC, 'r') as f:
    for i in range(NUM_CLASSES):
        class_names[i] = f.readline().strip()

label_map = {value: class_names[int(key)-1] 
             for key, value in train_gen.class_indices.items()}

# Model
adam = Adam(lr=LR)
dn121 = DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
model = build_model(dn121, LAYER_UNITS, NUM_CLASSES)
model.compile(adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Checkpoints

if not os.path.isdir(CHECKPOINT_DIR):
    os.makedirs(CHECKPOINT_DIR)
checkpoint_path = CHECKPOINT_DIR + MODEL_NAME + '.h5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor='val_acc', 
                             verbose=1, save_weights_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks = [checkpoint]

# Check for pretrained weights
if os.path.isfile(checkpoint_path):
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
else:
    # Train
    _ = model.fit_generator(
        train_gen, 
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        steps_per_epoch=NUM_TRAINING_SAMPLES // BATCH_SIZE,
        validation_data=val_gen, 
        validation_steps=NUM_VAL_SAMPLES // BATCH_SIZE,
        shuffle=True,
        callbacks=callbacks)



# Predict
test_batch_x, test_batch_y = test_gen.next()
pred_batch = model.predict(test_gen)
print(pred_batch)
test_labels = np.argmax(test_batch_y, axis=1)
test_pred = np.argmax(pred_batch, axis=1)

print(test_pred)
print(test_labels)
test_acc = sum(test_labels == test_pred) / len(test_labels)
print('Accuracy: %.3f' % test_acc)
```

File "", line 3, in 
        test_acc = sum(test_labels == test_pred) / len(test_labels)

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

i trying find the accuracy of the model by above method. i checked shaped of the **test_pred** and **test_labels**, they are different shape, but i don't know to change them

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by `test_labels` and `test_pred` not having the same shape.

If you compare two numpy arrays with different shapes the result is a boolean `False`.

Therefore `sum(False)` is called, which raises the type error

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

I can not exactly say why they are different shapes, but I would suggest printing out the shapes of the different variable before and after the prediction. If you post them here we can probably help you more.